# How to get function from function type?

Tags: reflection, julia

Suppose I have hold of the concrete type of a normal, named Julia function, `F = typeof(f)`.  Is it possible to get back `f` from `F`?  I assume this should work in principle, since `F` is a singleton type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with `Core.Compiler.singleton_type` function which returns the `instance` field for a concrete `DataType`. I think this function is used for the same objective as yours (not only for this objective) in `Core.Compiler` during compilation. This is probably considered "more internal" than directly accessing `instance` field.

```
julia> Core.Compiler.singleton_type(typeof(sum))
sum (generic function with 13 methods)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `F.instance`, but maybe there is some better solution (as this one is using the internals).